# IE 11 doesn't focus on span with tabindex

Tags: html, angular, internet-explorer, accessibility, tabindex

#### Setup:

We have an angular 5.x webapp which features a tree-component. It's basically a `<ul>`-List with a roving tabindex for keyboard navigation.
The HTML is a little more complex due to the layout of the tree-component and it features some recursiveness.

#### Problem:

We noticed a weird behavior in Internet Explorer when testing the TAB-focus. In the code-example below, you can see the `<span>` in line 8 has a `tabindex="0"` and should therefore be focusable via TAB-Key. The other nodes should not be focusable at this point. Now **only** in IE 11 the element is absolutely not focusable via keynavigation. All other browsers that were tested (Chrome, Edge, Firefox) handle the task just fine.

**Question:** Why is IE 11 not focussing the `span` with `tabindex="0"` ?

#### Example HTML for an angular component that reproduces the Issue:

```
<div id="hostDivForTree">
<ul class="subtree">
    <li class="item ng-star-inserted" >
        <a class="toggleLink ng-star-inserted">
            <i class="icon arrow"></i>
        </a>
        <a disabled="false" class="nodeName expanded" id="treeIndex_0" data-tag="none">
            <span tabindex="0" class="label">Marketing</span>
        </a>
        <div class="collapse ng-star-inserted" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false" style="height: auto; overflow: visible; display: block;">
            <ul class="subtree">
                <li class="item ng-star-inserted">
                    <a disabled="false" class="nodeName leaf" id="treeIndex_0_0" data-tag="good">
                        <span tabindex="-1" class="label">Level 1</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="item ng-star-inserted" >
                    <a disabled="false" class="nodeName leaf" id="treeIndex_0_1" data-tag="none">
                        <span tabindex="-1" class="label">Level 2</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <!-- ... -->
    <!-- Here go further li - items like the one before - its recursive -->     
    <!-- ... -->
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is probably that your `span` elements reside inside `<a>` tags.

Check caniuse.com footnote 2:

> `<a>` elements are never keyboard-focusable, even if they have `tabindex="0"`.
>
> https://caniuse.com/#search=tabindex

Also note that `disabled="false"` does not do what you might expect it to do. **The mere presence of a `disabled`-attribute means that it is disabled**, *regardless* of the value you assign to it (aside from `false` not being a valid value, only `disabled` is a valid value).

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Eventhough the footnote acutally refers to MacOS and Safari and not IE, I'll try to rebuild the tree-structure without anchors and see if that helps! --> I'll accept the answer if it does!

Comment: your answer is right! The part concerning the `<a>`-tags is helpful and important for the MacOS world. AND the actual problem with IE derives from the presence of the `disabled` property!